# How can we show predicted images resulted from segmentation model during training process?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I am training a segmentation model using the cityscape images by UNET model. The input is 256*256 image and the output is 1024*2048 image. So, I want to show the predicted 1024*2048 image every 20 epochs during the training. I am using keras in the implementation.

````
unet.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=masked_loss_function, metrics=[masked_accuracy])
mc = ModelCheckpoint(mode='min', 
                     filepath='cityscape_unet.h5', 
                     monitor='val_loss', 
                     save_best_only='True', 
                     save_weights_only='True', 
                     verbose=1)
callbacks = [mc]
history=unet.fit(train_gen, steps_per_epoch=steps, epochs=70, 
         validation_data=val_gen, callbacks=callbacks)```
````

Answer (score 1):

This could be easily implemented using a callback. When inheriting from `tf.keras.callbacks.Callback`, you can override the `on_epoch_end` method which you can change to display plots after an epoch ends. The method takes two arguments - `epoch`, and `logs`. `on_epoch_end` is called with the current epoch number starting from 0. So, you can easily add a conditional with this. Below is some boilerplate code.

```
class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomCallback, self).__init__()
    
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        if epoch % 20 == 0:
            # Do something here
            pass
```

Then, you can pass this callback into your callbacks list when training.